# Escaping reserved characters from a string stored in custom setting

Tags: apex, customsetting, string, escape

I want to get mykey stored in custom setting and escape the reserved characteres.

```
originalstring  = 'abc123def'pqr456\eryt' ; 

// escaping the reserved charatcters
String mykeyAfterEscapingReservedCharacters = 'abc123def\'pqr456\\eryt' ;
```

If I escape the reserved characters directly in Apex code, I get the output correctly. However if store the string mykeyAfterEscapingReservedCharacters = abc123def\'pqr456\eryt in the custom setting and access it in apex code I get an error because the reserved characters are not escaped.

```
customsetting cs = new customsetting.getInstance(); 
string mystringfromcustomsetting = cs.mykeyAfterEscapingReservedCharacters; 
systeom.debug(mystringfromcustomsetting );   
//  output = abc123def\'pqr456\\eryt
```

Comment: For what purpose are you escaping characters? What specific code results in an error, and what is the verbatim text of the error? Please [edit] to add details.

Comment: This string is used in HMAC authentication, it has reserved characters. it throws an error 'Unable to autheticate Authrorization header'

Comment: Please **[edit] your post** to show the actual failing code and error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding it as an answer because I don't have enough reputation for a comment.
Apex String class has methods for escaping and unescaping characters in the String. Maybe you would want to try those. 
For instance:

```
String s = 'Company: \\"Salesforce.com\\"';
String unescapedStr = s.unescapeJava();
System.assertEquals('Company: "Salesforce.com"', unescapedStr);
```

Here are the links:
[Apex String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) 
[Blog article for escapaing and unescaping](https://www.mstsolutions.com/technical/escape-and-unescape-string-methods-in-salesforce/)

Comment: Thank you ! This works. However the test class fails.  I will post a new question.