# Test Class Failing due to NullPointerException

Tags: apex, customsetting, escape

I have stored the SharedSecret and AccesskeyId in a custom setting.

The shared secret has reserved characters. This is a sample sharedsecret 'abc'\1@pQr&^%HGF45abcc'

In apex code I am accessing the shared secret like this

```
CustomSetting__c cs = CustomSetting__c.getInstance();
string secretAccessKeyUnEsc =cs.SecretAccessKey__c;
string secretAccessKey  = secretAccessKeyUnEsc.unescapeJava();
```

However my test class fails.

```
public class MyController {

    public static String getAPIData(String dealerId){

        // Asign the custom setting values
        CustomSetting__c cs = CustomSetting __c.getInstance();
        system.debug(cs);  

       string algorithmName = cs.Algorithmn__c;  

       string accessKeyID = cs.AccessKeyId__c;
       system.debug('AccessKeyId: ' +accessKeyID);  

       // escape the reserved characters (‘ and / from sharedsecret)
       string secretAccessKeyUnEsc =cs.SecretAccessKey__c;
       string secretAccessKey  = secretAccessKeyUnEsc.unescapeJava();
       system.debug('SharedSecret: ' +secretAccessKey);  

       string host = cs.Host__c;
       system.debug('Host: ' +host); 
       string endpoint = cs.End_Point_URL__c +dealerId;
       system.debug('Endpoint: ' + endpoint);   
    }
    public static List<Map<string, integer>> getGraph(String accountid){
      .......
    }
}
```

Here's my test class

```
    @isTest
      private class MyControllerTest {
        static testMethod void validateChart() {
       Id RecordTypeIdAcc = 
       Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Sales Account').getRecordTypeId();
       Account obj = New Account(Name='Test',External_ID__c='KZ4WE',recordtypeid = RecordTypeIdAcc);
       insert obj;

       // Custom setting record 
       CASIntegration__c mycs = CASIntegration__c.getInstance();

       CASIntegration__c csobj = New CASIntegration__c();
       csobj.AccessKeyId__c= mycs.AccessKeyId__c;
       csobj.SecretAccessKey__c = mycs.SecretAccessKey__c.unescapeJava();    

       csobj.Algorithmn__c = mycs.Algorithmn__c;
       csobj.Host__c = mycs.Host__c;
       csobj.End_Point_URL__c =  mycs.End_Point_URL__c;
       insert csobj;

       Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyAuthMock());  
       Test.startTest();
       MyController.getGraph(obj.Id); 
       Test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

The error:

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

```
At this line - 
string secretAccessKey  = secretAccessKeyUnEsc.unescapeJava();
```

Comment: Please check post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273288/escaping-reserved-characters-from-a-string-stored-in-custom-setting for your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't even shared if your `Custom Setting` is `List` or `Hierarchy` type. I will assume the latter, but basically the problem is that `CustomSetting__c.getInstance().SecretAccessKey__c` is null.  You have to create your own test data, which you seem to understand based on the fact you insert an `Account` to test against. The same goes for custom settings. They are just data. You need to insert a `CustomSetting__c` record which will be retrieved when you call `getInstance`, and on that record you need to populate `SecretAccessKey__c`.

Comment: Thanks @adrianLarson for the response. As suggested, I have created the custom setting data in test class, yet its failing. Please See edited body of the question